# Power BI - Need a slicer to look at multiple columns of Data

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am learning PowerBI as i go along and have been able to solve most issues faced by a quick google. Unfortunately this problem has baffled me.
We have thousands of lines of data which include a "Home Country" column & "Away Country" column.

What we need our slicer to do is to is to pick up for example Australia in both of these columns and display the results.

I currently have a table created using the below:

```
    slicercountrytable = distinct(
    Union(
    Values('All Data'[Home Country]),
    Values('All Data'[Away Country])))'''
```

and then a measure:

```
    Measure = 
    if(
    Min('All Data'[Home Country]) in values (slicercountrytable[Country])
    || Min('All Data'[Away Country]) in values (slicercountrytable[Country]),
    1,
    Blank()
    )
```

And have also tried the below measure:

```
    Measure 3 = VAR
    Searchvalue=search(SELECTEDVALUE(slicercountrytable[Country]),SELECTEDVALUE('All Data'[Combined Country]),,Blank())
    Return
    If(Searchvalue > 0,"Found")
```

I need the slicer to control the entire sheet however the above are doing nothing.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like your DAX for 'Measure' is good. But you will have to add it individually to all visuals -- it does not work at the page or 'all pages' level.  This has to do with scope and cannot be avoided.  Filter each visual so [Measure] "is not blank" and it ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, instead of building some complicated DAX I suggest to work the model.

Let's say your current table looks like that:

| id | home country | away country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B |
| 2 | B | C |

You may want to deal with that in another table by **unpivoting `home_country` and `away_country` in PowerQuery**.

In order to have a `country` table like that:

| id | country | attribute |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | home |
| 1 | B | away |
| 2 | B | home |
| 2 | C | away |

Then you link this new table to your existing one on `id` and filter/slice in it.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your example and feel that it is already showing the desired behavior.  I think the problem you might be running into is that you will now need to add your 'measure' filter to each and every visual individually.  It cannot be added to 'Page' or 'All Pages' filter areas.  This is because of the way a measure's calculation varies across context and cannot be avoided.

[image]

**DAX**

```
Table 2 = distinct(union(all('Table'[Away]), all('Table'[Home])))
```

---

```
Measure = 
if(
     MAX('Table'[Away]) in VALUES('Table 2'[SelectedCountries])
        || MAX('Table'[Home]) in VALUES('Table 2'[SelectedCountries]) ,
     1,
     blank()    
)
```